# ASP.NET Core Web App appsettings.json values replaced by random strings in docker container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that has some values stored in appsettings.json which are being accessed through the IConfiguration service. 
This works fine when the app is published and hosted in IIS on a windows machine. However when running in a linux docker container the values in appsettings are replaced with random strings such as `7d5136967af41`. 
The appsettings file is set to always copy to the output directory

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Update="appsettings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

I'm not sure where this problem is coming from so I will add the docker file too

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj", "ProjectName/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProjectName"
RUN dotnet build "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectName.dll"]
```

There are no errors when running `docker build -t imagename -f ProjectName/Dockerfile .` and no errors in the docker container logs

If any other files are need let me know and I will add them too, any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you create publish with '--self-contained' option?

Comment: The publishing to test in IIS I have not, but to publish for docker I have

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this issue too, it seems that using an appsetting of "Hostname" was the issue for, changing the name to anything else resolved the issue for me

Hope this helps